# Replace function call with pipe in angular template

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Read the benefits of using pipes versus invoking functions in angular templates. see vid here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ZvpdRM1eQ

I have this function in my template.html

```
<h1 [class]="alignText()" [innerHtml]="data.text"></h1>
```

And the function in my component.template.ts

```
  alignText(): string {
    let defaultText = "center";
    return "text-" + (this.text || defaultText)
  }
```

Anyone has suggestions how I could concert the html `alignText()` to a pipe to accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to Angular's documentation on Pipes: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

You can use the `@Pipe` decorator on a class for pipes. It should implement the `PipeTransform` interface which requires implementing a `transform` method that takes the value and returns a new value. `transform` can take additional arguments if needed.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'alignClass' })
export class AlignClassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return `text-${value || "center"}`;
  }
}
```

Add this pipe to `declarations` in your module. Now you can use `[class]="text | alignClass"`

Comment: Could I possibly share data between the component and the pipe.  The data I have is coming via:   export class TextComponent extends Component {}